# Jquery Ordering img position

Tags: jquery, image

I am trying to order my images on page like an hexagon.I found solution for this on java and now I am trying to implement it on Jquery. Firstly I  crated my photo list div element

```
<div class="photoList">
<?php $categories = find_category();

 foreach($categories as $category): ?>
<div id="userList"> 
 <img id="<?Php echo $category['cat_id']; ?>" src = <?Php echo $category['cat_image']; ?> />
</div>
 <?php endforeach ;?>
</div>
```

It gets all element source from database and show them on page top to bottom .

Then I used Jquery for changing each element position on page

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var cx = $(window).height()/2;
 var cy=$(window).width()/2;
 var  $userList= $('.userList img').size();

 var polyXX = new Array("30","25","0" ,"-25","-30","-25","0","25");
 var polyYY = new Array("0","22","30" ,"22","0","-22","-30","-22");
 var count =5;

   for ( var i = 1; i < $userList; ++i ) {
 drawHexes(cx,cy); 
   }
 function drawHexes(cx,cy){ 
 count = Math.min ( 20, Math.min ( cx, cy )/20  );


        for ( var rank = 1; rank < count; ++rank ) {

            for ( var bar = 0; bar < 8; ++bar ) {
                var x = ( polyXX [ ( bar + 6 ) % 8 ] + polyXX[ ( bar + 7 ) % 8 ] ) * rank;
                var y= ( polyYY [ ( bar +6 ) % 8 ] + polyYY [ ( bar + 7 ) % 8 ] ) * rank;

                var dx =polyXX [ bar ] + polyXX [ ( bar + 1 ) %8 ];
                var dy = polyYY [ bar ] + polyYY [ ( bar + 1 ) %8 ];


              for ( var hex = 0; hex < rank; ++hex ) {
 $('.userList img').css({'left':(cx+x)+'px' ,'top':(cy+y)+'px'} );

                    x += dx;
                    y += dy;

                }
            }    
  }   
 } 

});
```

But this is not doing any effect.All photos are the same position. They must be like an hexagon.  I thing I have problem with this line `$('.userList img').css({'left':(cx+x)+'px' ,'top':(cy+y)+'px'} );`

And here post for creating hexagon in Java. [creating 10.000 connected hexagon page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687176/creating-10-000-connected-hexagon-page)

**EDIT **

I made console.bug and as result 
cx=298 
cy=403.3
 x=25
 y=NaN 
dx=3025
 dy=022

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing the values of `(cx+x)+'px'` and `(cy+y)+'px'`?

You are entering a typecasting minefield with these statements.

Check out an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ASC5k/

**Edit**

To ensure you are adding two integers, use `parseInt(cx,10)`. E.g.

```
cx = parseInt(cx,10);
```

Comment: @Meko. Not entirely sure what your asking. See edit, this might help

Comment: it worked but now All my images move the same direction.Is there any way to choose each img separate and add them unique  left and top position?

Comment: Do you want to accept that as an answer then? I don't understand what you're asking latterly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you apply `position: absolute` to your images? And by the way, you missed the quotes for the `src`-attribute in this line (corrected version):

```
<img id="<?php echo $category['cat_id']; ?>" src="<?php echo $category['cat_image']; ?>" />
```

Comment: Yes in my main.css I apply position:absolute.