# Custom layout Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I want to make board(map) like this in Java.

[image]

Each small hexagon is image.

Suppose I have two Java classes. Canvas(big hexagon) and Hexagon. First is entire board from which I generate randomly all small hexagons. Both classes derived from JPanel. Now I have GridLayout. How can I arrange layout like this?

Comment: gridLayout does rows and columns.  Yours would have to overlap.   You might have to use absolute positioning (no layout manager).

Comment: If you may, Try your hands at [GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html), that might help you sort things out.

Comment: May I suggest a completely different approach: Don't use a toolkit which is designed to create Desktop-Applications for games.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need the small hexagon panels? 
I would rather just define List (list of Hexagons) each with desired position and just override `paintComponent()` method of main `JPanel`. You can use this http://java-sl.com/shapes.html to create hexagon shapes.

To track mouse click you can use contains() method of Shape.

Comment: +1 This related [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3687176/230513) has a nice sscce and some tips on the geometry.

Answer (score 3):

you can

1) common way

- by painting to the `JPanel/JComponent` by override `paintComponent()` (I asumed that there are `Image/BufferedImage/Icon/ImageIco`n)

2) by place `Icon/ImageIcon` to the `JLabel`

- you have look at [JLayer (since Java7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) or use (former) `JXLayer`
- [OverlayLayout](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1401__OverlayLayout.htm) or customizations for [OverlayLayout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/) by @camickr

Comment: +1 but the most difficult thing is to handle mouse events for the overlapping hexagons.

Answer (score 1):

The point of layout manages is to make it possible for the layout to auto-adjust when components change their size or the window does.

It looks like your hexagons will always be the same size, so you really don't need a layout manager, and positioning the hexagons absolutely should be fine.