# Doing a non-square game board in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently working on implementing a puzzle game, one of which is a game called sixpack. the pieces are triangular, and are assembled into hexagons, with groups of hexagons assembled into a diamond shape. it looks something like this:

[image: sixpack board]

my first thought was to put a bunch of jbuttons on top of that image you see, which i made in illustrator, using exact positioning. however i was wondering if there is a better, more scalable approach anyone else can think of that uses one of the swing layout managers.

Comment: I think the best idea is to use paintComponent().

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3687176/230513).